# mod-rewrite, how to implement a second rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get a `.htaccess` file `RewriteRule` in my web application. I need a double rule to match two URL formats that might happen:

Rule 1 (not commented below and works like a charm)

```
    http://example.com/whatever -> /index.php?page=whatever&
    http://example.com/whatever/ -> /index.php?page=whatever&
    http://example.com/whatever/?test=me -> /index.php?page=whatever&test=me
```

Rule 2 (commented out below and does not work, but should work like this)

```
  http://example.com/api/ -> index.php?page=api&func= 
  http://example.com/api/whateverelse -> index.php?page=api&func=whateverelse
```

The folder `/api/` does not exists on the server and by reading the documentation the `L` parameters should prevent the parsing of more rules. Yet if I uncomment the `^\/api\/(.*)$` I get an 404 response.

The goal is that if the first rule gets parsed the second rule is omitted, and the goal is that the first rule actually works.

Is there someone that could point me in the right direction here?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^\/api\/(.*)$    //index.php?page=api&func=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^\/?([^\/]+)\/?$ //index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

I tried to debug it by adding: 
    `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6`

but this is not allowed in the `.htaccess` and I do not have direct access to the server configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #RewriteRule ^\/api\/(.*)$    //index.php?page=api&func=$1 [NC,L]
> ```

This doesn't work because in `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. You have included a slash prefix on the regex, so it never matches.

In the following rule, the slash prefix is made optional with the `?` quantifier, ie. `^\/?` - so it will match. (The slash prefix is only required when the directive is used in a server context. By making it "optional", it would work in either.)

If you are only using `.htaccess` then you can remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *pattern* altogether.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) /index.php?page=api&func=$1 [NC,L]
```

Additional notes...

- No need to backslash escape slashes in the regex, as they carry no special meaning. (Apache uses *spaces* as argument delimiters.)
- Not sure what the double slash prefix on the *substitution* string was for? ie. `//index.php`. You should only have at most one slash here, or none at all for an internal rewrite (and the `index.php` file is in the same directory as the `.htaccess` file). (The double slash still "works", only because Apache is reducing instances of multiple slashes when it maps the URL to the filesystem.)
- The `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` directive that follows, so you may need to repeat these for the second rule. (Or reverse the logic and stop processing when a request *does* map to a file/directory? However, this might depend on what other directives you have in the file.) If you don't have physical files that start `/api` then you can remove the conditions from that rule.
- You don't need to manually append the `QUERY_STRING` to the *substitution*. This is what the `QSA` (Query String Append) flag is for. The `QSA` flag will also avoid a stray `&` at the end when no query string is present on the request.
- The `NC` flag is not required on the last rule. It may not be required on the "api" rule either, unless `/API`, or `/ApI` etc. might be required - but this should be avoided.

So, bringing this together, we have....

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*) /index.php?page=api&func=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```